# undefined variable in livewire

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire, livewires

i use laravel 8 . and livewire 2.0.
without any variable in the blade  it working normally but if use any  variable it gives Undefined variable: but this variable is declared in class, i try all solutions but the problem not working ca anyone give me an idea

```
    ErrorException
Undefined variable: input(View:C:\xampp\htdocs\sis\resources\views\livewire\admin\grade\addgrade.blade.php)
Hide solutions
$input is undefine
```

the route   Route::view('/add_grades', 'livewire/Admin/Grade/Addgrade')->name('admin.grades.add');.

the blade is

```
 {{$input}}
```

and the class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Grade;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Livewire;
use phpDocumentor\Reflection\Types\This;

class Addgrade extends Livewire
{
    public $input= 0 ;
    public function render()
    {

        return view('livewire.admin.grade.addgrade');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your livewire blade view needs to have a base div:

```php
<div>
    {{ $input }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with the your route as the $input parameter is not initialized.

Try replacing:

```
Route::view('/add_grades', 'livewire/Admin/Grade/Addgrade')->name('admin.grades.add');
```

with:

```
Route::get('/add_grades', \App\Http\Livewire\Addgrade::class);
```

If you have already imported the livewire component in your route file, you can use this instead:

```
Route::get('/add_grades', Addgrade::class);
```

NB: if *\App\Http\Livewire\Addgrade::class* is not the path to your livewire component change that.